# Differences between github API commit statuses "failure" and "error"?

Tags: git, github, github-api, git-commit

What is the difference between github API commit statuses "failure" and "error"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [GitHub API Statuses](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/) do include marking commits with a success, failure, error, or pending state.

Typically, in a [continuous integration context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration), a commit is:

- marked as [**failed**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Failure) because the job failed to *complete*
- marked as [**error**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error#Science_and_engineering) because the job *did complete*, but exited with a *non-zero status*
- marked as **success** because the job did complete, and exited with a zero status

(job as tasks run by [job scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_scheduler))

---

Since 2014, the integration of GitHub with CI did evolve.
In May 2018, you had "[Introducing the Checks API, a better way to connect integrations and code](https://github.blog/2018-05-07-introducing-checks-api/)".
It introduced the notion of **[checks](https://developer.github.com/v3/checks/)**

> Rather than binary pass/fail build statuses, integrations can report rich statuses, annotate lines of code with detailed information, and kick off reruns.

You find failure in that new context (of checks)

[image: https://developer.github.com/assets/images/check_runs.png]

> When someone pushes code to a repository, GitHub creates a check suite for the last commit. GitHub Apps with the `checks:write` permission receive a check_suite webhook with the requested action. When your GitHub App receives the check_suite event, it can create new check runs for the latest commit.

This works with:

- [Travis-CI](https://blog.travis-ci.com/2018-05-07-announcing-support-for-github-checks-api-on-travis-ci-com) (which has since then [deprecated the GitHub commit status API updates for GitHub Apps-managed repositories](https://blog.travis-ci.com/2018-09-27-deprecating-github-commit-status-api-for-github-apps-managed-repositories))
- [Circle-CI](https://circleci.com/integrations/github/)

In that new context ([New Checks API public beta](https://developer.github.com/changes/2018-05-07-new-checks-api-public-beta/)):

- failure is associated with a check which runs, but exit with a non-zero status,
- error is associate with a check which cannot even run

See [Questions](https://developer.github.com/changes/2018-05-07-new-checks-api-public-beta/#questions):

> ### How are check runs different than commit statuses?
>
> Commit statuses allow for a simple pass or fail state.
> Check runs allow for much more granular information: they can conclude as either success, failure, neutral, cancelled, timed_out, or action_required. Check runs are more flexible than commit statuses.

---

From [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1184752/juraj-martinka)

[Juraj Martinka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1184752/juraj-martinka):

> In unit testing terminology:
>
> - "failure" usually represents a failed test, that is the code under the test returned an answer but this is different from the expected one;
> - "error" represents an unexpected error in the code like an exception being thrown.
>
> This is also what I've seen to be used in CI such as Travis:
>
> - "build failed" means that your change breaks some tests, has linter errors, etc.
> - "build error" means unexpected build job error (early termination).

[Bob Bell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/564327/bob-bell) agrees:

> I use:
>
> - "failure" to say "the test failed against the criteria", and
> - "error" to be "the test was not able to be executed properly".
>
> I consider "failure" and "success" to be opposite, the two results of a completed test, while "error" is the outlier, the result of an aborted test.

Comment: Hi! Could you explain please is this your personal opinion? Because the person in the other answer has official comment from github support.

Comment: @AlexanderMyshov No, it is what I have seen with most CI I have used. However, the official GitHub answer alludes to "GitHub checks", which were introduced 4 years after this answer. I have edited my answer to document that.

Comment: In unit testing terminology, "failure" usually represents a failed test, that is the code under the test returned an answer but this is different from the expected one; "error" represents an unexpected error in the code like an exception being thrown.
This is also what I've seen to be used in CI such as Travi - "build failed" means that your change breaks some tests, has linter errors, etc. "build error" means unexpected build job error (early termination).

Comment: I agree with @JurajMartinka.  I use "failure" to say "the test failed against the criteria", and "error" to be "the test was not able to be executed properly".  I consider "failure" and "success" to be opposite, the two results of a completed test, while "error" is the outlier, the result of an aborted test.

Comment: @BobBell Good point. Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 11):

I asked this question from official GitHub and received next response:

> Hi Alexander,
>
> Thanks for contacting GitHub Support!t
>
> - A failed CI check is when the check has not passed the required conditions.
> - A CI check that is in error is when the check itself has an error that prevents it from running correctly.
>
> Let me know if you need any further information.